# I'm having issues with a code to determine if a number is a prime number or not

Tags: c++

I'm supposed to find if a given number is a prime number or not until given the quit number which is -1. When I input a number, it'll either come back as all prime numbers or all negative numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int number, count;

count = 0;

cout << "Enter positive numbers. Enter -1 to quit." << endl;
cout << "Enter number: ";
cin >> number;

while (number != -1)
{
    for (int i = 2; i <= number-1; i++)
    {
        if (number%i == 1)
            count++;
            break;
    }
    if (count == 1)
        cout << number << " is not prime number" << endl;
    else
        cout << number << " is prime number" << endl;

    cout << "Enter number: ";
    cin >> number;
}
cout << "Program is terminated";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through your code?

Answer (score 1):

1. In this line

   ```
   if (number%i == 1)
   ```

   you most probably want to find out "if `number` is divisible by `i`", which is equivalent to "the remainder of `number` divided by `i` is **zero**". Hence you need to write

   ```
   if (number%i == 0)
   ```
2. Your `break;` is strange. As it currently is, it is **not** within the `if`-block and hence you break out of the loop in the very first iteration. You should enclose the body of your `if` with curly braces:

   ```
   if (number%i == 1) {
       count++;
       break;
   }
   ```
3. The variable `count` needs to be reset to zero after (or before) each prime number test. Or better: move its declaration just before the for-loop to avoid such *unintended reuse of old values*.
4. Please write the whole prime number test as a function. This also drops the need for both the `count` variable as well as for the `break`, as you can simply `return` as soon as you found a divisor. This in turn would have eliminated problems 2. and 3. completely.
5. As an optimization, you can observe that you only need to check until `i*i > number`. That's true since if a greater `i` could be a divisor, the result of the division would be *smaller than `i`*, and hence you'd already have found it earlier. So use `i*i <= number` as the condition in the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see is the idea of `count++`. If the program is called again, then we have our old count. If we have our old count, then if the next number is prime, it is actually telling us that the number is not prime. Similarly, if we keep going through this count and come across a non prime number, then we make count to be 2. This is an even bigger problem, because now we are saying non primes are primes.

As an aside, I have a function written in C [on github](https://github.com/Twoody/integers_that_divide_me/blob/master/main.c) that does some stuff `isprime`.

Best of luck!

Comment: Completely off topic but those end of line `/**/` comments in your `C` code are horrific and anyone that has to maintain your code will hate you forever.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I have been told this recently... I guess it is an old habit that I have regarding keeping my code organized. What is a good way to do something similar, but without the stupid boxes?

Comment: My dumb advice is to completely forget about padding out the lines in any way. I don't think it improves readability, it's a fiddly nightmare to keep it all in sync (unless your text editor does it automatically, but what about the poor maintenance programmer with a different editor), and it bloats the size of your source files.

Comment: Oh, and one practical issue is it prevents me from commenting out a few lines of code. When I insert `/*` to start a block your `/**/` will end the block and make me very sad.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I'll take that to heart. I actually showed your comment to a few peers, and they all laughed do to them saying the same exact thing. To get rid of the text editor problem, I tend to use spaces instead of tabs (again, bad habits). Still, to the point, I'll be breaking this habit as of now :)

Comment: For an alliterative organizational structure, look at explicit [code folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_folding) most IDEs and editors support it in some way, shape, or form.

Comment: @MichaelT, Thanks for the advice! I'll check it out as soon as I get some free time :)